# Nested scroll- composable inside xml view

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-xml

I have a recyclerview where one of the viewholders holds a composable that is a scrollable list. The nested scrolling here is not working by default resulting on the composable list to not scroll. I have tried using nested scroll connection but it doesn't seem to work for me. how can i produce this behavior?